# What is the correct way to include subdomains to the Django sitemap urls?

Tags: python, django, sitemap, subdomain, django-sitemaps

I have my development site (localhost.com 'as on the development machine').

This domain has got two subdomains, `developer` and `blog`.

The url configuration for sitemaps are,

```
from django.contrib.sitemaps.views import sitemap, index as sitemap_index

url(r'^sitemap\.xml$', sitemap_index, {'sitemaps': sitemaps},
    name='django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap'),

url(r'^sitemap-(?P<section>.+)\.xml', sitemap, {'sitemaps': sitemaps}),
```

when creating sitemaps with sitemap index,
The site maps are created as

```xml
<sitemap>
<loc>http://localhost.com/sitemap-blog.xml?p=2</loc>
</sitemap>
<sitemap>
<loc>http://localhost.com/sitemap-blog.xml?p=3</loc>
</sitemap>
<sitemap>
<loc>http://localhost.com/sitemap-blog.xml?p=4</loc>
</sitemap>
```

I want the sitemap on the subdomain, that is `blog.example.com`

so I overwrote the `index` view on `django.contrib.sitemap.views` by changing the absolute_url to `blog.sitemaps` as follows

```
from django.contrib.sitemaps.views import x_robots_tag
from django.contrib.sites.shortcuts import get_current_site
from django.core import urlresolvers
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse

@x_robots_tag
def index(request, sitemaps,
          template_name='sitemap_index.xml', content_type='application/xml',
          sitemap_url_name='django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap'):

    req_protocol = request.scheme
    req_site = get_current_site(request)

    sites = []
    for section, site in sitemaps.items():
        if callable(site):
            site = site()
        protocol = req_protocol if site.protocol is None else site.protocol
        sitemap_url = urlresolvers.reverse(
            sitemap_url_name, kwargs={'section': section})
        absolute_url = '%s://blog.%s%s' % (protocol, req_site.domain, sitemap_url)
        sites.append(absolute_url)
        for page in range(2, site.paginator.num_pages + 1):
            sites.append('%s?p=%s' % (absolute_url, page))

    return TemplateResponse(request, template_name, {'sitemaps': sites},
                            content_type=content_type)
```

So the output the subdomain index is something like this,

```xml
<sitemap>
<loc>http://blog.localhost.com/sitemap-whos.xml?p=3</loc>
</sitemap>
<sitemap>
<loc>http://blog.localhost.com/sitemap-whos.xml?p=4</loc>
</sitemap>
```

What is the correct way to make django sitemap framework to pick up the dynamic subdomains to the sitemap url?

I use `django-subdomains` package

Answer (score 4):

Marty!

I've found a great solution for my needs:

1. No need in `django-subdomains`, just use  simple middleware taken from [here](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1119/):

   ```
   class SubdomainMiddleware:
   """ Make the subdomain publicly available to classes """

       def process_request(self, request):
           domain_parts = request.get_host().split('.')
           if (len(domain_parts) > 2):
               subdomain = domain_parts[0]
               if (subdomain.lower() == 'www'):
                   subdomain = None
               domain = '.'.join(domain_parts[1:])
           else:
               subdomain = None
               domain = request.get_host()

           request.subdomain = subdomain
           request.domain = domain
   ```
2. If you don't use '[sitemap index](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/sitemaps/#creating-a-sitemap-index)' alter `sitemap` view in `django.contrib.sitemap.views` by adding two variables `req_domain` and `req_subdomain` that are now in all `request`s:

find

```
    req_protocol = request.scheme
    req_site = get_current_site(request)
```

add two new lines:

```
    req_domain = request.domain
    req_subdomain = request.subdomain
```

then find

```
    urls.extend(site.get_urls(page=page, site=req_site,
                                  protocol=req_protocol))
```

and make it look like this:

```
    urls.extend(site.get_urls(page=page, site=req_site, r_domain=req_domain, 
                                  r_subdomain=req_subdomain, protocol=req_protocol))
```

3. Now alter `__init__.py` in `sitemap` root dir:

in `class Sitemap` make `get_urls` function look like this `def get_urls(self, page=1, r_domain=None, r_subdomain=None, site=None, protocol=None)`

find th line `domain = site.domain`, comment it out and add below:

```
domain = r_domain
subdomain = r_subdomain
```

now alter this code below:

```
if getattr(self, 'i18n', False):
        urls = []
        current_lang_code = translation.get_language()
        for lang_code, lang_name in settings.LANGUAGES:
            translation.activate(lang_code)
            urls += self._urls(page, protocol, domain)
        translation.activate(current_lang_code)
    else:
        urls = self._urls(page, protocol, domain)

    return urls
```

so it looks like this:

```
if getattr(self, 'i18n', False):
        urls = []
        current_lang_code = translation.get_language()
        for lang_code, lang_name in settings.LANGUAGES:
            translation.activate(lang_code)
            urls += self._urls(page, protocol, domain, subdomain)
        translation.activate(current_lang_code)
    else:
        urls = self._urls(page, protocol, domain, subdomain)

    return urls
```

4. find `def _urls(self, page, protocol, domain)` function below and make it look like this `def _urls(self, page, protocol, domain, subdomain)`

and in this function below find:

```
loc = "%s://%s%s" % (protocol, domain, self.__get('location', item))
```

and replace it with this:

```
loc = "%s://%s.%s%s" % (protocol, subdomain, domain, self.__get('location', item))
```

5. profit!

Answer (score 3):

You can simply override `_urls()` method in your sitemap class and include a super call with the domain as the subdomain + host form.

```
class BlogSitemap(Sitemap):
    def _urls(self, page, protocol, domain):
        return super(BlogSitemap, self)._urls(
            page=page, protocol=protocol, domain='docs.djangoproject.com')
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution extends just two classes to create a set of reuseable components for sitemaps with subdomains.

First I created a new SubdomainSite class implementing the interface of `django.contrib.sites.models.Site`

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible


@python_2_unicode_compatible
class SubdomainSite(object):
    """
    SubdomainSite shares the interface of Site and adds subdomain support.
    """
    def __init__(self, subdomain, site=None):
        self.subdomain = subdomain
        self.extend_site(site)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.domain

    def extend_site(self, site):
        """Always returns the root level site extended with subdomain."""
        if issubclass(site.__class__, self.__class__):
            return self.extend_site(site.root_site)
        elif hasattr(site, 'domain'):
            self.root_site = site
        self.domain = self.name = '{0}.{1}'.format(self.subdomain, site)
        return self

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False):
        raise NotImplementedError('RequestSite cannot be saved.')

    def delete(self):
        raise NotImplementedError('RequestSite cannot be deleted.')
```

This is then used with a class `SubdomainSitemap` I created which extends Sitemap. This class only adds a subdomain attribute and adds two lines to `get_urls` - it's not as complicated as it looks, the original class just crams a little too much into one function.

```
from django.contrib.sitemaps import Sitemap


class SubdomainSitemap(Sitemap):
    """Adds subdomain support to sitemaps"""
    subdomain = None

    def get_urls(self, page=1, site=None, protocol=None):
        """Always uses this sitemap's subdomain if supplied."""
        # Determine protocol
        if self.protocol is not None:
            protocol = self.protocol
        if protocol is None:
            protocol = 'http'

        # Determine domain
        if site is None and self.subdomain is None:
            if django_apps.is_installed('django.contrib.sites'):
                Site = django_apps.get_model('sites.Site')
                try:
                    site = Site.objects.get_current()
                except Site.DoesNotExist:
                    pass
            if site is None:
                raise ImproperlyConfigured(
                    "To use sitemaps, either enable the sites framework or pass "
                    "a Site/RequestSite object in your view."
                )
        else:
            # Setting a subdomain site overrides supplied site
            site = self.subdomain
        domain = site.domain

        if getattr(self, 'i18n', False):
            urls = []
            current_lang_code = translation.get_language()
            for lang_code, lang_name in settings.LANGUAGES:
                translation.activate(lang_code)
                urls += self._urls(page, protocol, domain)
            translation.activate(current_lang_code)
        else:
            urls = self._urls(page, protocol, domain)

        return urls
```

Now tie it all together in your sitemaps classes!

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
from sitemaps import SubdomainSite, SubdomainSitemap
from blog.models import Post

current_site = Site.objects.get_current()


class BlogSitemap(SubdomainSitemap):
    changefreq = 'monthly'
    subdomain = SubdomainSite('blog', current_site)
    protocol = 'https'

    def items(self):
        return Post.objects.all()
```

Voila!

Answer (score 1):

For a more general version of [All Іѕ Vаиітy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45893348/446338) answer you can use this for any subdomain you might need:

```
class FixedSitemap(Sitemap):
    priority = 0.5
    changefreq = 'monthly'
    protocol = 'https'

    def items(self):
        # Add all your items here
        return ['docs.yourdomain.io']

    def location(self, obj):
        return obj

    def _urls(self, page, protocol, domain):
        return super(FixedSitemap, self)._urls(page, protocol, '')
```